# Could vue3 <script setup> use component is, how to make it work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new beginner of vue3 and found that vue have three way to write component:

- <script setup>
- normal-setup/composition api
- options api.

I know how to use  in normal composition api like this:

```
<script>
import CommonLayout from "@/components/Layout/CommonLayout.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    CommonLayout,
  },
  setup() {
    const layout = "CommonLayout";
    return { layout };
  },
};
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    {{ layout }}
    <component :is="layout">123</component>
  </div>
</template>
```

it really works.

but I try to use setup script, it failed:

```
<script setup>
import CommonLayout from "@/components/Layout/CommonLayout.vue";
const layout = "CommonLayout";
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    {{ layout }}
    <component :is="layout">123</component>
  </div>
</template>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use imported name:

```
<script setup>
  import CommonLayout from "@/components/Layout/CommonLayout.vue";
</script>
<template>
  <CommonLayout />
</template>
```

or dynamically:

```
<script setup>
  import CommonLayout from "@/components/Layout/CommonLayout.vue";
</script>
<template>
   <component :is="CommonLayout" />
</template>
```

or you can use alias

```
<script setup>
  import { CommonLayout as Layout } from '@/components/Layout/CommonLayout.vue';
</script>
<template>
   <component :is="Layout" />
</template>
```

Comment: So I cannot use the name  to make it work right? In options api, I can use a string name to use `component is` with putting the component in components option

Comment: @radiorz hey mate, you need to use imported name or create alias like `import { CommonLayout as Layout } from '@/components/Layout/CommonLayout.vue'`